# add a break line on a ImprovedTable in fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I would like to know if it is possible to add a line break in ImprovedTable

```
$pdf->ImprovedTable($header,$data);
```

for information, $data is build like this :

```
$sql->selectFrom(array('id','libelle','questionnement'),'question');
            $sql->addWhere('ref_questionnaire', '=', $ref_questionnaire);
            $questions = $sql->save();

            $cpt = 1;
            $cptLigne = 1;

            $data = array();
            // pour chaque question
            foreach ($questions as $question)
            {                                        
                $ligneTab = array(); 

                //$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
                $ligneTabQuest = $cpt.')';
                $ligneTabQuest .= utf8_decode($question->libelle);

                $ligneTab[] = $ligneTabQuest;
```

...

Comment: What about the special character `\n`?

Comment: I don't know when I have to add this \n, it's randomize